# Is there any way in React Hooks we can changes the value of input tag on the click of onClick Function

Tags: reactjs

This is code m this card is dynamic and I'm trying to change the value of input value on click for specific input which have unique id or name attribute, in the below code, how can I achieve this?

I have tried with useRefs also but basically when I am trying to increment the quantity it reflected in all cards which are coming dynamically

```
const [productList, setProductList] = useState([]);
const [quantityCount, setQuantityCount] = useState(0);
const [incremental, setIncremental] = useState();
const countRefs = useRef(0);

const incrementHandler = event => {
  setQuantityCount(prev => prev + 1);
  //var event = new Event('input',{bubbles:true})
  //this.myinput.dispatchEvent(event)
};
const decrement = () => {
  if (quantityCount !== 0) {
    setQuantityCount(quantityCount - 1);
  }
};
const updateIncrementValue = evt => {
  console.log(evt);
};
useEffect(() => {
  Axios.get(ENV.URL + "/category", {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  })
    .then(response => {
      setProductList(response.data);
    })
    .then(error => {
      //console.log(error)
    });
}, []);

const handlerRequest = e => {};

return (
  <>
    {productList.map(item => {
      return (
        <div className="col-md-4 mb-4" key={item.id}>
          {item.subCategories.map(el => {
            return (
              <div className="card-deck" key={el.id}>
                {el.products.map(e => {
                  return (
                    <div className="card" key={e.id}>
                      <div className="featuredImg">
                        <span className="discount">
                          <small>Discount</small>
                          <br />
                          {e.discount}%
                        </span>
                        <img className="card-img-top" src={e.imgUrl} alt="" />
                      </div>
                      <div className="card-body">
                        <h5 className="card-title">{e.name}</h5>
                        <p className="card-text">{e.description}</p>
                      </div>
                      <div className="card-footer">
                        <h6>${e.price}</h6>
                        <Link to="/" className="cartbtn">
                          Add Cart
                        </Link>
                        <div className="input-group">
                          <input
                            type="button"
                            defaultValue="-"
                            className="button-minus"
                            onClick={decrement}
                          />
                          **{" "}
                          <input
                            type="number"
                            id={"quantity" + e.id}
                            name={"quantity" + e.id}
                            value={quantityCount}
                            onChange={handlerRequest}
                            className="quantity-field"
                            readOnly
                          />
                          **
                          <input
                            type="button"
                            defaultValue="+"
                            className="button-plus"
                            onClick={() => incrementHandler(e.id)}
                          />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

map can take in 2 arguments 2nd one gives the index of your element you can send the index as an argument in your onclick in the array when you get the index you can update the item

here in the code below i have made a simple list in which you can increase a products quantity.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [productList, setProductList] = useState([
    { id: 1, product: "p1", quantity: 0 },
    { id: 2, product: "p2", quantity: 0 },
    { id: 3, product: "p3", quantity: 0 },
    { id: 4, product: "p4", quantity: 0 },
    { id: 5, product: "p5", quantity: 0 }
  ]);

  const handleIncrement = index => {
    let newProductList = [...productList];

    newProductList[index] = {
      ...productList[index],
      quantity: productList[index].quantity + 1
    };

    setProductList(newProductList);
  };
  return (
    <>
      {productList.map((SingleProduct, index) => (
        <div>
          <h1>{SingleProduct.product}</h1>
          <h1>{SingleProduct.quantity}</h1>
          <button onClick={() => handleIncrement(index)}>increase</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what *actually* represents an object in your `productList`'s (nested) arrays, but presumably there is a quantifiable "quantity" property that has a one-to-one relationship to every item `e` mapped. It appears you've some really nested data so the handler needs to be able to handle the nesting, i.e. identifying what element in each array at each nested level. You've three levels, "products", "sub categories", and "product". Passing the specific id of each level is necessary. Using a functional state update you shallowly copy the array at each level and when the id's match, update *that* specific array element.

```
const incrementHandler = (itemId, elId, id) => {
  setProductList(productList =>
    productList.map(item =>
      item.id === itemId
        ? item.map(el =>
            el.id === elId
              ? el.map(e =>
                  e.id === id ? { ...e, quantity: e.quantity + 1 } : e
                )
              : el
          )
        : item
    )
  );
};
```

The onClick handler now needs to pass all parameters

```
onClick={() => incrementHandler(item.id, el.id, e.id)}
```